# Tableau DocuSign Integration

Tags: docusignapi, tableau-api

We have several DocuSign Accounts in our organization. We are planning to build Tableau dashboard that gets usage/billing data from all accounts.  DocuSign is using OAuth Token for authentication. Not sure how to authenticate in Tableau.
Could you help us with this?

https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Billing/Invoices/get

Answer (score 0):

doesn't look like Tableau supports OAuth, https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_concepts_auth.htm says you have to provide the email/password in the request

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to create a [Web Data Connector](http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/) that retrieves the data from DocuSign and puts it into a tabular format for Tableau to use.

Tableau can only connect to SQL datasources, datasources with an ODBC connector, or web data connectors that translate non-SQL sources (such as DocuSign's REST API) into a tabular form.

Answer (score 0):

This [example from Tableau](http://tableau.github.io/webdataconnector/docs/wdc_oauth_tutorial.html) shows how to oauth authenticate with the data source (DocuSign in this case)